# entity framework 4 and sql server datatype (nchar vs char)

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

i'm developing a web app application and I'm using EntityFramework ObjectModel to design my Model layer.

The matter is that I've some string fields (like 'CodiceFiscale', an unique identifier for people in Italy) that should be 16 char long. The designer let me make it fixed length, max length = 16, but it means the field will be nchar(16) in sql server.

Is there any chance to set that field as char (I'd like to avoid field padding at the end)

thx in advance

Comment: `CHAR` and `NCHAR` are **both** fixed-length. If you want to avoid padding at the end, you need to use `VARCHAR/NVARCHAR` instead!

Comment: mh, you're right marc_s, it was my mistake. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `MaxLength = 16, FixedLength = false` settings in your model:

[image]

That ought to result in a `NVARCHAR(16)` column, and that's what you're looking for.

Comment: i understood the mistake. i've set "fixed length" property to "true", because of this it creates a nchar column. thx a lot!